# method getSupportFragmentManager() is undefined for the type CadastroModoVoo

Tags: java, android, datepicker

I'm trying to create a `DatePicker` within a Fragment and returns the error  The method `getSupportFragmentManager()` is undefined for the type `CadastroModoVoo`. What  is wrong?

XML:

```
<Button android:id="@+id/selectHora3Button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:onClick="selectHora3"
        android:text="Hora" />
```

Class:

```
public class CadastroModoVoo extends Fragment {
    private FragmentActivity context;


    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        cadastro_modo_voo = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cadastro_modo_voo, container, false);
        context = getActivity();



        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
        @SuppressLint({ "ValidFragment", "NewApi" })
        public void selectHora3(View view)  {
            qual = 3;
            DialogFragment newFragment = new SelectTimeFragment();
            newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "TimePicker"); -----> error
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Call it on your context variable like `context.getSupportFragmentManager()`. [Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html#getSupportFragmentManager%28%29)

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that, indeed, the class Fragment does not have a method called getSupportFragmentManager(). That method is only in FragmentActivity.

For android.support.v4.app.Fragments I think the correct method to call would be getChildFragmentManager().

EDIT: Now that I'm reading roarster's answer, I am not sure which FragmentManager you actually need for your DialogFragment - the one returned by getChildFragmentManager or the returned be context.getSupportFragmentManager()... Can't try it out at the moment...